# My BT Branded 2-Wire HGV2700 aka BT2700HGV fails to download large files (gets stuck) from the playstation store when using my playstation 3

Tags: ps3, adsl-router

My BT Branded 2-Wire HGV2700 aka "2701HGV" fails to download large files from the playstation store when using my playstation 3

How can I fix this...

Hardware Version: 2701-100589-005
Firmware Version: 6.3.9.63-plus.tm

PS3 says error 80710723

Symptoms:

Playstation store downloads of files over 2GB just get stuck and never finish

Comment: It is probably something to do with an update and not anything to do with enhanced services. You blocked all security updates to your router to fix bugs in the playstations network stack. Congratulations Sony p.s. I am using an OpenBSD firewall with this issue which suddenly started happening after an upgrade possibly around more secure handling of fragmented traffic being enforced.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the router firmware.

Someone smart has come up with a workaround that avoids having to connect a device directly to the router and use PPPoE... (which is another way of solving it but requires the ps3 to be directly plugged into the router.. not great in a home network situation)

http://bt2700hgv.tripod.com/161.htm

Scroll down to

History of 2+GB file download testing

The bug is in "Enhanced Services (Content screening & Access
controls)" it causes regular HTTP downloads of large files to "freeze"
midway and never finish. e.g. most movies and Games on the playstation store!!!

The workaround is essence is...

1. unplug the router
2. reset it to factory default (removing those "enhanced" services)
3. configure router offline... block the router from being able to contact BT's "Provisioning servers"
   so that it can't download any BT services or updates (by setting up static routes to a local address that doesn't exist) ....Blocks all upgrades and communications between hub and BT motive.com servers.
4. reconnect and configure to connect as normal

Quite clever really whoever thought that one up!

It works!

I'd say this is for "advanced users" only but is a GREAT alternative to buying another router.... and can be quite easily removed again if they ever sort out the firmware to fix this problem....

There were rumours of this being fixed in some of the later v6 firmwares but sadly for me it was still happening on:

Hardware Version: 2701-100589-005
Firmware Version: 6.3.9.63-plus.tm

Just incase the forum link stops working I'll mention the static routes that need to be created to block the router from being able to access the provisioning / update servers:

> Now go to Settings → Broadband → Routing page.
>
> Enter the following two static routes. You may use an alternative
>   'unused' local IP address instead of 192.168.1.250 shown below for
>   your configured LAN:
>
> Subnet IP: 66.193.112.0, Subnet Mask: 255.255.254.0, Gateway IP:
>   192.168.1.250 Subnet IP: 64.186.176.0, Subnet Mask: 255.255.240.0, Gateway IP: 192.168.1.250